# spring boot permitAll only works with HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests()

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am creating an api using spring boot

but I am getting the error below

permitAll only works with HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests()

```
      http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "index", "/css/*", "/js/*")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole(STUDENT.name())
            .antMatchers("/admin/api/**").hasRole(ADMIN.name())
            .antMatchers("/management/api/**").hasAnyRole(ADMIN.name(), ADMINTRAINEE.name())
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll();
```

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: refer to this link 
https://www.yawintutor.com/illegalstateexception-permitall-only-works-with-httpsecurity-authorizerequests/

Comment: @VipulPandey I have tried the solutions but did not work for me

Comment: remove `permitAll` after `loginPage`

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko Thanks for your reply. I have done that but it did not work for me